# Redefinition errors in .h files

Tags: c

```
//list.h file
typedef struct _lnode{
    struct _lnode *next;
    size_t row;
    size_t column;
    short data;
}lnode;

typedef struct _llist{
    struct _lnode *head;
    size_t size;

}llist;

//matrix.h file
typedef struct _matrix{

    size_t width;
    size_t height;
    size_t k;

    int **data;

}matrix;

//smatrix.h file
#include "list.h"
#include "matrix.h"

typedef struct _smatrix{
    size_t width;
    size_t height;
    size_t k;

    llist data;
}smatrix;

smatrix* make_smatrix(matrix *m);
```

smatrix.h file includes list.h file and matrix.h files. If I include those header files in smatrix.h file then I get

```
 redefinition of 'lnode'. redefinition of '_llist' and redefinition of '_matrix' errors.
```

If I took those heder files our from smatrix.h file then the error went away but it complains about matrix type in the function parameter. I want to call functions defined in list.h and matrix.h files in smatrix.c file.. What do I do? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Possible problem of multiple inclusions.

Try to guard your header files with `#ifndef` [read about it here](https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/ifndef.html)

file list.h

```
#ifndef _LISTH_
#define _LISTH_

<your code>

#endif
```

file matrix.h

```
#ifndef _MATRIXH_
#define _MATRIXH_

<your code>

#endif
```

It will prevent you too have redefinitions if you have a loop in header inclusions.

Answer (score 8):

you need [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your header files.

Answer (score 2):

Well from your posted code what I think is missing is at the beginning of each *.h file:

```
#ifndef _some_unique_identifier_for_each_header 
#define _some_unique_identifier_for_each_header

...header contents

#endif //_some_unique_identifier_for_each_header
```

or a

```
#pragma once
```

if your compiler supports it.

Without this, if the header is included multiple times from various sources you get errors relating to redefinition.

Answer (score 1):

You probably include `smatrix.h` and `list.h` in some other file. You should avoid that. The usual way to do that is to use `include guards`.

These are macros that you check with `#ifdef` at the beginning of the file (with `#endif` in the end), and `#define` them inside the `#ifdef ... #endif`, thus insuring that even if you do include the same file multiple times, the compiler will only read it once, at the first time, and skip all the rest.