# The class has been defined, but the program claims it is redefined

Tags: c++

So I have this one error and just like the title it is a class type redefinition error. I have looked at the previous posts about this type of error and tried to use their solutions; however none of them worked.

This is the header file for employee.h

```
class Employee { 
public:
    Employee();
    void getHours();
    void getSalary();
    void getVacationDays();
    void getVacationForm();
};
```

And this is the employee.cpp

```
#include "employee.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void Employee::getHours(){
    cout << " I work 40 hours per week\n";
};
void Employee::getSalary(){
    cout << " I earn $40, 000\n";
};
void Employee::getVacationDays(){
    cout << " I receive 2 weeks vacation\n";
};
void Employee::getVacationForm(){
    cout << " Use the yellow vacation form \n";
};
```

I have ran the files before and they worked perfectly fine, but when I made a derived class, "Marketer" the program suddenly breaks at some point.

This is the marketer.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "employee.h"
using namespace std;
class Marketer: public Employee
{
public:
    Marketer();
    void Marketer::getPay();
    void Marketer::getTime();
    void Marketer::getDayOff();
    void Marketer::getForm();
};
```

and this is the Marketer.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Marketer.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void Marketer::getTime(){
    cout << " I work 40 hours per week\n";
};
void Marketer::getPay(){
    cout << " I earn $50, 000\n";
};
void Marketer::getDayOff(){
    cout << " I receive 2 weeks vacation\n";
};
void Marketer::getForm(){
    cout << " Use the yellow vacation form \n";
};
```

When I run the program it only gives me an error saying

```
"Error C2011: 'Employee' :'class' type is redefined".
```

I find no errors in employee.h/.cpp nor Marketer.h/.cpp
Does anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: Use include guards. That is, in Employee.h, add `#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H_ #define EMPLOYEE_H_` (separate lines) at the very top, and at bottom add `#endif `

Comment: Do your headers have [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)?

Comment: Oh and do the same for Marketer.h. Any header file you create, actually.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Well timed

Comment: possible duplicate of [C, redefinition errors in .h files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430019/c-redefinition-errors-in-h-files)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your .h is only parsed once. #pragma once or #ifndef myheader_h ...